# yasnippet : How to expand snippet inside snippet?

Tags: yasnippet

In yasnippet's manual expansion of snippet inside a snippet is mentioned but I wasn't able to achieve this.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

I have two snippets :

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: newhist
# key: newhist
# expand-env: ((yas-triggers-in-field 't))
# --
${1:-- }----------------------------------------------------------------------------
${2:_head}$2
$1Objet        : ${4:Objet}$0
```

and

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: _head
# key: _head
# --
${1:-- }Auteur       : `(and (boundp 'user-ngram) user-ngram)`
$1Date         : `(capitalize (format-time-string "%d/%m/%Y"))`
$1Version      : `(and (boundp 'global-release) global-release)`.00.${2:0001}$0
```

And I expect something like that after expansion :

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Auteur       : me
-- Date         : 29/09/2016
-- Version      : 513.00.0001
-- Objet        : Objet
```

But all I get is :

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
_head_head
-- Objet        : Objet
```

Comment: See also [yasnippet #558](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/558 "Import snippets into other snippets").

Answer (score 4):

you need to add this to your `yasnippet` config in `.emacs` to enable nested triggering of snippets

`(setq yas-triggers-in-field t)`

Comment: I try to do that but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pierre You have to move point to the end of `_head` and then press `TAB`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `yas-triggers-in-field` is to bind `yas-expand` to a key (I use `C-<tab>`), and then use this key to expand when you're already in a snippet.

It has the benefit that you'd only get expansion when you want to, TAB would by default not perform expansion when you're already in a snippet (unlike using `yas-triggers-in-field`).